# Rank Multiple Columns in One Spreadsheet in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have a large spreadsheet in MS Excel 2003 with multiple two column pairings. Col A has names and Col B has numbers. Col C and D are blank. I need to rank the numbers in Col B from least to greatest using the numbers 1-10 in Col C and Col D remains blank. This situation repeats itself about 5 times throughout the spreadsheet. Therefore, I cannot actually swap any rows or columns or even cells, I just need to add simple numbers to blank cells. I think this can be done in Excel 2010 but is there some type of workaround for Excel 2003? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What have you tried? It isn't particularly clear what you're trying to do here.

Is there any reason why you can't use the `rank` function to do this? Do you have more than 10 rows in columns A and B, and if so are you trying to allocate them into 10 quantiles of the values in column B rather than ranking them?

Comment: You are exactly right. I overcomplicated the issue and looked and it from a wrong and stupid angle. The Rank function should work just fine thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use the RANK() function in column C.

=RANK(C2,C$2:C$50)